# On Pixel 7a Android AOSP

Tags: android, flash, android-source

I currently want to install a stable version of AOSP android-14.0.0_r15 on my Pixel 7a(lynx)

When trying to flash I get the following error:

```
/out/target/product/lynx# fastboot flashall -w
target reported max download size of 261095424 bytes
Invalid sparse file format at header magic
Invalid sparse file format at header magic
wiping userdata...
Erase successful, but not automatically formatting.
File system type raw not supported.
--------------------------------------------
Bootloader Version...: lynx-14.0-11170085
Baseband Version.....: g5300q-230927-231106-B-11056121
Serial Number........: XXXXX
--------------------------------------------
checking product...
OKAY [  0.016s]
checking partition-exists...
FAILED (remote: variable (partition-exists) not found)
finished. total time: 0.100s  .
```

I have not been able to locate this version android-14.0.0_r15 on https://flash.android.com/

Fortunately my Pixel hasn't bricked, but I still can't do the correct flash.

Could you help me see how I can install AOSP android-14.0.0_r15 on my mobile?

Thanks in advance!